# Simple SQL Insert

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert, sql-server-ce

I'm new to databases and am trying to add a new record using SQL. The code runs fine the first time, but the second time throws an error saying that it can't write duplicates to a unique key. The third time runs fine, but the fourth time throws the error. Basically, it seems that every other time, the error is thrown. I understand why the error would be thrown if data was written, but when I examine the database, it remains empty. What am I doing wrong in my code that is causing the query to not bother writing the data?

**EDIT** If I enter the SQL directly within the database, it works. It doesn't work when I use the C# code below.

```
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO User (Name, Age, URL) VALUES ( @name, @age, @url )", con))
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "James Y");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", 28);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", "www.example.com" );
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm.. Are you using transactions outside of this method? what happens between the 2nd and the 3rd time? if you run it only once and check the database, do you see any row?

Comment: Not doing anything else. I've created a new console application, added a SQL-CE 4 server and the above is the only custom code in the entire program. Only thing I haven't included is the one line getting the connection string. If I run it once, then check the database, it's still empty. Btw, I'm following this tutorial http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlce and wanted to extend the 'Insert Values' section since my table has multiple columns.

Comment: How about this: if you are operating within a transaction, the first insert succeeds, the second throws an exception because of the unique constraint violation. The exception rolls back the transaction and you are back to the initial state.

Comment: What is the entire error message? Does it indicate which field? How are the fields defined in the DB?

Comment: URL is a unique Primary Key and that's the violated field. @Glenn - If   I run it once, no errors are thrown, but nothing is written either. Entire message is `A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = User,Constraint name = PK_User ]`

Comment: Update - I noticed if I keep running the program quickly each time the console window closes, the error message is consistently thrown.

Comment: Seems you use a primary key but the identity specification is set to "no" (by default).

Comment: @Skoder That still fits the transaction scenario. The first insert succeeds, would be visible in that session only, but is not yet committed. Nor does it ever get committed because the second statement throws an exception and throws the entire transaction back (including your first insert). To verify, do a commit between your first insert and the second that fails. Then you will see the record remaining in the db.

Comment: @Glenn - I tried adding `com.Transaction.Commit();` after the executenonquery method but it throws an `Null Reference Exception` on the `Transaction` property.

Comment: @Skoder Not familiar with c# sql stuff, but looking at this url, there is a bit more to creating and committing a transaction. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Can you add your connection string (without password and server info) to the post.

Comment: @Glenn - Thanks, I'll look into that but I'm following the tutorial posted earlier and it seems that for the basics, it should just work. Maybe multiple values are different. @Graymatter - No passwords or anything, just a new, local database. `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ WebsiteThreeDB.sdf` - got it from `Properties.Settings.Default.WebsiteThreeDBConnectionString;`

Comment: This may just be a version issue between the SQL Compact and .NET libraries.

Comment: Possibly, I'll see if I can find a more up to date tutorial.

Comment: name is a reserved word. wrap it in []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've partially figured it out. Apparently you have to also download `SQL CE Tools for Visual Studio`. I did this and I had a new option to include SQL CE 4 into my project (I was using the SQLCE option, assuming that it would use 4.0 by default since that's the one I installed). Only problem now is that when I try and add it, it says that it's not supported by the project type (Console project). I saw a post on MSDN that said that SQLCE 4 was for web-only projects but it was a post from a few months back and the current download page says it's for web or desktop applications. Either way, this is proving to be too much of a hassle to bother with and so I'm just going to look for an alternate database if I can't resolve this soon.

**FIXED** I uninstalled SQLCE4 and the SQLCE Tools, then reinstalled them.

Answer (score 0):

Try and do the following as your SQL:

```
INSERT INTO [User] (Name, Age, URL) VALUES ( @name, @age, @url )
```

User is a reserved word in sql server. You should try not to name your table as "user".

Comment: Nope. Since I'm just following a tutorial, I created a new table called 'RandomName' but it still throws the error. Interestingly, if I execute the SQL directly from the Database, it works fine. It only seems to throw the error when I'm using C#.

Comment: Try adding con.Close() before the end of the using block. SQL can do very weird things if you don't close connections.

Comment: @Graymatter is con.Dispose() not equals to con.Close() ?

Comment: Maybe a dumb suggestion but have you tried adding the parameters with the types like this com.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 28;

Comment: Dispose does close the connection for SqlConnection but I am not sure about SqlCeConnection. We have had instances (with an oracle provider) that did not close the connection when disposed and this has made me extremely paranoid with it.

Answer (score 0):

Name is a reserved word.  Wrap it in []

```
using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO User ([Name], Age, URL) VALUES ( @name, @age, @url )", con))
```

Comment: I've recreated the project with a completely new name 'RandomName', but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use DataDirectory in your connection string, the file is copied to your bin/debug folder, so you have several copies of the database, one in your project and one in your debug folder. Make the connection string a full path to avoid any confusion while debugging!

Comment: I'm afraid it's irrelevant now as even loading an SQL 4 database isn't working (see my answer).